How to compress AVAudioPCMBuffer to Data for streaming and playback the compressed Data
I am trying to record my microphone, compress the recorded audio buffer, transfer the compressed buffer as bytes to another device, decompress the received bytes into a new buffer and finally playback that buffer.
The following code I use to record the microphone, and to test whether the compression and decompression works without issues (thus leaving out the data transfer part):
    // ... code to setup audioEngines for recording and playback

    tappableInputNode?.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024, format: format!) { (buffer, when) in
      guard let compressedData = compressPCMBuffer(buffer) else {
        print("Failed to compress buffer")
        return
      }

      guard let decompressedBuffer = decompressDataToPCMBuffer(compressedData) else {
        print("Failed to decompress data")
        return
      }

      let renderTime =
        playerNode.playerTime(
          forNodeTime: playerNode.lastRenderTime ?? AVAudioTime(hostTime: mach_absolute_time()))
        ?? AVAudioTime(hostTime: mach_absolute_time())

      let delayInSeconds = 0.1
      let futureHostTime = renderTime.hostTime + UInt64(delayInSeconds)
      let scheduledTime = AVAudioTime(hostTime: futureHostTime)

      playerNode.scheduleBuffer(decompressedBuffer, at: scheduledTime, completionCallbackType: .dataPlayedBack) { (type) in
        print("Buffer played back")
      }
      playerNode.play()
    }

When playing the initial buffer provided by the tap, everything works fine. But when I try to playback the decompressed Buffer (like in the code above), the only thing I hear is a fast clicking sound.
Recording of the audio output
For compressing the AVAudioPCMBuffer I wrote the following function:
public func compressPCMBuffer(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> Data? {
  var error: NSError?
  var opusDesc = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
  opusDesc.mFormatID = kAudioFormatOpus
  opusDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = buffer.format.channelCount
  opusDesc.mSampleRate = buffer.format.sampleRate
  guard let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &opusDesc) else {
    print("Failed to create AVAudioFormat")
    return nil
  }
  guard let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: buffer.format, to: audioFormat) else {
    print("Failed to initialize AVAudioConverter")
    return nil
  }

  let outputBuffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer(
    format: audioFormat, packetCapacity: 1, maximumPacketSize: 512
  )

  let inputBlock: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
    outStatus.pointee = .haveData
    return buffer
  }

  let status = converter.convert(to: outputBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputBlock)
  if status == .error || error != nil {
    print("Audio conversion failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
    return nil
  }

  let packetCount = Int(outputBuffer.packetCount)
  if packetCount == 0 {
    print("No packets were produced during conversion")
    return nil
  }

  let data = outputBuffer.toData()
  
  return data
}

The returned data seems to be 160 - 180 bytes of size, ideal for my use case.
Then, for decompressing the Data to an AVAudioPCMBuffer I have this function:
public func decompressDataToPCMBuffer(_ rawData: Data) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
  var opusDesc = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
  opusDesc.mFormatID = kAudioFormatOpus
  opusDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
  opusDesc.mSampleRate = 48000
  guard let opusFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &opusDesc) else {
    print("Failed to create Opus AVAudioFormat")
    return nil
  }

  let inputBuffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer(
    format: opusFormat, packetCapacity: 1, maximumPacketSize: 512
  )
  inputBuffer.packetCount = 1
  inputBuffer.byteLength = UInt32(rawData.count)
  rawData.withUnsafeBytes { (rawBufferPointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
    let rawPointer = rawBufferPointer.baseAddress!
    inputBuffer.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mData!.copyMemory(
      from: rawPointer, byteCount: rawData.count
    )
  }

  guard
    let pcmFormat = AVAudioFormat(
      commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: opusDesc.mSampleRate,
      channels: AVAudioChannelCount(opusDesc.mChannelsPerFrame), interleaved: false
    )
  else {
    print("Failed to create PCM format")
    return nil
  }

  guard let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: opusFormat, to: pcmFormat) else {
    print("Failed to create AVAudioConverter")
    return nil
  }

  guard let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: pcmFormat, frameCapacity: 4800) else {
    print("Failed to create PCM buffer")
    return nil
  }

  var error: NSError? = nil
  let inputBlock: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
    outStatus.pointee = .haveData
    return inputBuffer
  }

  converter.convert(to: pcmBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputBlock)
  if let error = error {
    print("Error during conversion: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return nil
  }

  return pcmBuffer
}

Both functions run correctly without any warnings or errors, but the played audio is corrupted / malformed, with the clicking sound I described earlier.
I have also tried other formats, like AAC, but I get the exact same clicking sound.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

I was unable to create my own compression / decompression functions. However, I was able to get it to work using a third party package. https://github.com/alta/swift-opus

AVAudioConverter promises to convert between a lot of audio codecs and their formats. The codecs have varying complexities and requirements on  how much input data they need before they can produce output and  AVAudioConverter's design reflects this. The header file documentation touches on this, making a distinction between "simple" (without callback) and "complex" conversions (with callback) - simple does not involve rate conversions or codecs, so is probably limited to simple LPCM format changes, float to int that kind of thing.
The two most obvious problems in your code are

the AVAudioConverters are recreated for every single audio buffer,
which defeats AVAudioConverter's ability to maintain state between buffers and removes its freedom to choose when and how many compressed or decompressed frames to give you - which is the whole point of the complex conversion with callback.

the code consumes a certain amount of output from each converter (512 packets for compression, and 512 frames for decompression). For decompression this may be too little, and by letting the  AVAudioConverter go out of scope, you will never get the remaining PCM data. Also, some codecs give you a bit of extra silence at the beginning of the stream. Either of these could explain the clicking.


So create the AVAudioConverters only once and consume all their available output. There may be other problems but I'm going to stop here.
